# ModelState does not work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I have a very simple application. Here's my view code;

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Kategori Modeli</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Category Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}
```

And here's my model code;

```cs
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Name cannot be null.")]
    [Range(3, 25, ErrorMessage = "Category Name must have 3-25 characters")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
```

And the Insert Code;

```cs
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Insert(Category _category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ---
        }
    }
```

ModelState.IsValid is always false even if it has 4 characters. Please help me. It always shows "Category Name must have 3-25 characters" error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range does not validate a string length. It checks a numeric value is between the specified numbers.

MaxLength and MinLength should be used.